# Prevent youtube exiting fullscreen when receiving IM from Pidgin

Tags: windows-vista, youtube, pidgin

A youtube video exits fullscreen when someone instant messages me on pidgin. I have Pidgin set to be minimized when for new conversation windows. Sadly I cant find an option to prevent this exit of youtube in full screen. This does not happen when Im watching a dvd in full screen though.

Is the only option available to me 'Hide New IM conversations' so the only alert is the system tray/notification area pidgin icon?

Thanks for any reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a problem with Flash, whereby any screen that gets focus pulls it out of full screen mode.  [Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5419028/keep-flash-videos-in-full-screen-on-dual-monitors) has an article on how to fix this (don't be fooled by dual monitor) it is useful on single monitor PCs as well.  The only caveat to this is I haven't tried this with the newest Flash.

Second [Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5560912/keep-flash-101-in-full-screen-on-a-second-monitor) article about Flash 10.1

Comment: This seems very useful, but it looks like it's Windows only. Any equivalent for a 64-bit Linux?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of anything for Linux, or any other OS other than Windows for that matter.